# How to convert "24cd2ec2-6674-4aa2-a761-1b0a953124ba"(String Object) into a BigDecimal

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a DB table `MyTable` which has a column `myColumn` of type `VARCHAR(20)`. I have a Spring MVC application which recieves a POST request at the controller level. I am trying to capture the Transaction ID of the request and set it to a field in the Entity Object which is of type `BigDecimal`. I get a `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

For example:

```
String transactionID = "24cd2ec2-6674-4aa2-a761-1b0a953124ba";
entity.setTransactionID(new BigDecimal(transactionID));
entity.save();
```

Any work around for this problem would be helpful.

Comment: Decimal numbers don't have hyphens in them.  Even if you treat that as hex, it's not going to be a valid number.

Comment: What number would you expect this to produce, and why?

Comment: If your entity has a type of BigDecimal, how are you getting a guid into the database in the first place?  Why aren't you using the same type for both?

Comment: I am unable to persist the entity into the DB because of this exception. I am exactly not sure why the DB field is of type VARCHAR and the field in the Entity class declared is of type BIGDECIMAL. @azurefrog

Comment: I expect to set this value to a field of type BigDecimal which resides in an Entity Class. ultimately i want to persist this entity that was set into the DB. @Joe C

Comment: Let's try this again: what number do you expect "24cd2ec2-6674-4aa2-a761-1b0a953124ba" to be?  I assume that it's not 42?

Comment: Updated the Post. It now may be clear what exactly I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to convert String to BigDecimal,the String should contain a numeric value convertible to a decimal.

E.g:-

```
String ID= "123.45";
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(ID)); // 123.45
```

If instead,

```
String ID= "12-fe3.45";
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(ID)); // throw java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

Comment: In case you want to save guid, use String instead of Bigdecimal in the entity class.

Comment: Thanks. This info helps. @DASH

Comment: @user8782239 If it's helpful, please consider marking it as the accepted answer